# how to manually concat a char **args to char *args

Tags: c

so I'm trying to write a function that concats a char**args to a char*args
What I have so far is":

```
char *concat(char **array)
{
int size = 0;
int i=0;
int j=0;
int z=0;
while (array[i]!=NULL)
{
    printf(" %s \n", array[i]);
    size = size + sizeof(array[i])-sizeof(char); //get the total size, minus the      
//size of the null pointer
    printf("%d \n",size);
    i++;
}
size = size+1; //add 1 to include 1 null termination at the end
char *newCommand = (char*) malloc(size);
i=0;
while(i<sizeof(newCommand))
{
    j=0;
    z=0;
    while (array[j][z]!='\0')
    {
        newCommand[i] = array[j][z];
        i++;
        z++;
    }
    j++;
}

newCommand[sizeof(newCommand)-1]='\0';
return newCommand;
```

}

this doesn't seem to work. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: For `sizeof(array[i])` etc you probably want `strlen(array[i])`. Other than that, you just need to do some basic debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this (untested):

```
int size = 0;
int count = 0;

while (array[count]) {
    size += strlen(array[i]);
    count++;
}

char *newCommand = malloc(size + 1);
char *p = newCommand;
newCommand[0] = 0; // Null-terminate for the case where count == 0

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    strcpy(p, array[i]);
    p += strlen(array[i]);
}
```

First, your size calculation was wrong. You wanted the size of the strings, but `sizeof(array[i])` gives you the size of a single element in your array which is a pointer and thus 4 (32-bit) or 8 (64-bit). You need to use `strlen` instead.

Next, your manual copying was also off. It's easier to do it with a moving pointer and `strcpy` (which is to be avoided normally but we've calculated the sizes with `strlen` already so it's OK here). The use of `strcpy` here also takes care of null termination.

Comment: Also, when concatenating you can usefully replace the `strcpy` and `strlen` with a call to `stpcpy`, defined as follows: `char *stpcpy(char *dst, const char *src) { while ((*dst++ = *src++)); return dst-1; }` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that you keep using `sizeof()` with a pointer argument, whereas I think you are trying to get the size of the corresponding array.

`sizeof()` can only give you information that's available at compile time, such as the sizes of raw types like `char` and `int`, and the sizes of arrays with a fixed length such as a `char[10]`. The sizes of the strings pointed to by a char* is only computable at run time, because it depends on the exact values passed to your function.

For `sizeof(newCommand)` you probably need `size`, and for `sizeof(array[i])`, you probably need `strlen(array[i])`.